# Linear programming / linear optimization video lectures?

Tags: linear-programming, online-resources

Is there a good set of linear programming / linear optimization video lectures somewhere?

I found "[Linear programming and Extensions](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC50F86BDF6873CED9)" by Prof. Prabha Sharma, Department of Mathematics and Statistics, Indian Institute of Technology Kanpur.

Are there other good ones? Thanks.

Comment: Syllabus for Prof. Prabha Sharma's course: http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/syllabus/syllabus.php?subjectId=111104027

Comment: https://archive.nptel.ac.in/content/syllabus_pdf/111104027.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Boyd's Convex Optimization [lectures](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/videos.html) are a good resource.

Comment: What's the key difference between convex optimization and linear optimization? @littleO

Comment: Thanks @littleO for the link to Prof Stephen Boyd's convex optimization video lectures. In Boyd's book titled [*Convex Optimization*](http://www.amazon.com/Convex-Optimization-Stephen-Boyd/dp/0521833787/), it is said that: *Convex optimization is a special class of mathematical optimization problems, which includes least-squares and linear programming problems. *We can consider convex optimization to be a generalization of linear programming. *Two very widely known and used special subclasses of convex optimization: least-squares and linear programming.

Comment: Bertsimas' text [*Introduction to Linear Optimization*](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Linear-Optimization-Scientific-Computation/dp/1886529191), p. 17: "linear programming can be used to solve problems with piecewise linear convex cost functions, and the latter class of functions can be used as an approximation of more general convex cost functions. On the other hand, such a piecewise linear approximation is not always a good idea because it can turn a smooth function into a nonsmooth one (piecewise linear functions have discontinuous derivatives)."

Answer (score 0):

Penn State Math 484, Linear Programming, 2016.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbxFfU5GKZz1Tm_9RR5M_uvdOXpJJ8LC3

Answer (score 0):

There's Wenshen's [Youtube Video Lectures](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbxFfU5GKZz1Tm_9RR5M_uvdOXpJJ8LC3&si=Hjkn-HSY1t9r6cV9), then there's Infinity Learn's Intro videos [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo6aRV-mbeg&list=PLmdFyQYShrjf2BlDFvO-kHT2ftf05yxfR&index=4), [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQFAvPF2OSI&list=PLmdFyQYShrjf2BlDFvO-kHT2ftf05yxfR&index=5), and [three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJFiR0DG2Bw&list=PLmdFyQYShrjf2BlDFvO-kHT2ftf05yxfR&index=6). Then there's Ezikian Acadamy and [his videos](https://www.youtube.com/@Ezikan/videos) (which aren't under a playlist, unfortunately), and then there's Dr. Bazett's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7TL5NMlKIk)

Comment: There's quite a few more, but I'll have to get permission to link those, so I'll update this later when I get that